# How to generate token for Authorization Code grant in ADFS enabled OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, adfs

i have been working for api automation framework in java and I need to automate the Oauth token generation through Authorization Code Grant Type.  Also i want to get the token without user intervention (ADFS userid and password will be provided in the config file). Is it possible to generate token like this? is that generated Authentication-code one time effort and reusable?

Please give me some advice?

Answer (score -1):

To Obtain access token for a resource in ADFS without a user please use the client credential flow. You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios#client-credentials-grant-flow) document.

Comment: Thanks Dhivya..I have tried but i am getting "MSIS9605: The client is not allowed to access the requested resource"

Comment: Thanks Sathiya, You might have to do an additional step to approve your application.
`Grant-AdfsApplicationPermission -ClientRoleIdentifier "clientId" -ServerRoleIdentifier "https://service.url"`. For reference you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/grant-adfsapplicationpermission?view=win10-ps)

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark the answer by clicking the up arrow and verify by clicking the emoji below. Doing so helps others find answers to their related questions.

Comment: @Sathiya  May i know the reason why there is a downvote for the answer ? did it not answer your question ?